# Speed Optimization with String Formatting

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, string-formatting

I have an application that searches through all of the SharePoint farm features and looks for specific features.
The names it pulls back are in an ugly format so I run them through a comparison to clean them up and then add them into an Xml node.  It goes as follows:

```
    if (featureName.Contains("target feature"))
    {
      if (featureName.Equals(Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_CACHE_SERVICE))
      {
        string cleanFeatureName = "Caching Service Feature";
        XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
        infoTree.Add(cleanName);
      }
      if (featureName.Equals(Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_IMAGE_SERVICE))
      {
       string cleanFeatureName = "Imaging Service Feature";
       XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
       infoTree.Add(cleanName);
      }
      if (featureName.Equals(Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_HEALTH_RULES))
      {
       string cleanFeatureName = "Health Rules";
       XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
       infoTree.Add(cleanName);
      }
      if (featureName.Equals(Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_INFRASTRUCTURE))
      {
       string cleanFeatureName = "Imaging Infrastructure";
       XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
       infoTree.Add(cleanName);
      }
      if (featureName.Equals(Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_MONITORING))
      {
       string cleanFeatureName = "Monitoring";
       XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
       infoTree.Add(cleanName);
      }
     }
```

It takes about 2.3-2.4 seconds on average to do this test.  Is there a better way I can format/replace these strings in a way that would improve speed?
I am looking into maybe doing a switch / case statement.

Comment: If your `Constants` are truly `const` then you can definitely use a switch/case. Regardless, set up a benchmarking test case and try the different options presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different things that you can do in order to speed up your code.  Im sure a switch statement might help, but one thing you should know about string.Equals is if you are using the same encoding, you should try ou the overload with the StringComparison Enum.  Using Ordinal, or OrdinalIgnoreCase (if you don't care about case), is actually much faster than the default Culture, or InvariantCulture.  This may affect your code if working on different culture machines with different sets of characters though.

```
if (featureName.Equals(Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_CACHE_SERVICE, StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

Here is what your swich would look like.  Obviously fill in your code between the cases, and always have a break at the end of each case (unless returning).  You will also need to add a default case, though you could just put a break in there to do nothing.

```
if (featureName.Contains("target feature"))
{
    switch(featureName)
    {
        case Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_CACHE_SERVICE:
            string cleanFeatureName = "Caching Service Feature";
            XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
            infoTree.Add(cleanName);
            break;
        case Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_IMAGE_SERVICE:
            //Code here
            break;
        case Constants.IMAGING_FEATURE_HEALTH_RULES:
            //etc
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: something for future reference I just found out:  case statements won't take the Constants."whatever" as acceptable because it doesn't know what the Constants file values are at compile time.  Switching it to local `const` variables fixed that issue.

Comment: Appologize, I was not aware of your entire environment.  I have no issues with constants defined in code, (because that is what a constant is).  If your constants are from a file, then they are more like config or properties.  That is a lightly confusing nomanclature, as if you read your "constants" out of a file (not dll), then you will have issues trying to use a switch statement.

Comment: Ah yes, I did not specify properly, the `Constants` is an attached file in the project.  I am sure it would work just fine the way you had it, it was just something interesting I found with my particular environment.

Answer (score 3):

you could put all needed replacement info into a `Dictionary<string,string>`... this would remove all `if` logic and just leave with a very fast dictionary lookup to acquire `cleanFeatureName` from the respective `Constants...`

In essence you would basically fill the `Dictionary` once on startup, then your code would lookup similar to this:

```
if (YourDictionary.ContainsKey (featureName))
{
string cleanFeatureName = YourDictionary[featureName];
XElement cleanName = new XElement("Item", cleanFeatureName);
infoTree.Add(cleanName);
}
```

This way you don't need any `featureName`-specific `if` clauses...

IF you access the `Dictionary` from different thread then use `ConcurrentDictionary` which is a very fast any thread-safe dictionary implementation available in .NET4 and up...

Comment: If performance is an issue, use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` instead of doing a contains + get operation. It's about a third faster.

Answer (score 1):

For what proportion of the calls is the first "if" true?

I need to know that to give you a full answer. If the answer is "most" then it might be quicker to remove that test altogether. Try it and see in any case.

However, for starters try changing all the .Equals() to .Equals(target, StringComparison.Ordinal) and see if that makes much difference.

You could also try replacing all the .Equals() with a switch statement.

Comment: The first "if" is true for only those 5 following strings.  So say, 5 out of...15-20? SharePoint farm features.